# How to infer Django model from json data?

Tags: python, json, django, database, django-models

I have a json file and I want to automatically generate Django model class code based on my json data.

What I search for is similar to [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/), but not with database, where I can connect legacy database to django and make `model.py` file out of it like `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`. But with json file instead of database.

Comment: Why don't you use a document database like mongodb or couchbase for this? It would be much simpler than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Django with Python3 has issues with supporting Mongodb

Comment: Is this json well defined or is it subject to change?

Comment: A subject to change, but not substantial, I suppose. It is a genetic experiment metadata obtained from `ArrayExpress` database via its python API, namely, `bioservices` package. It consists of experiment general information which is unified throughout database and of samples information which varies greatly from experiment to experiment.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) model serializers for converting json data from and to a Django model.
Defining a serializer for a model is straightforward and requires only defining the relevant fields for serialization.
In addition you can user more advance features as defining nested serializers (i.e serializers of objects refering to other objects), as well as using various validations for the serialization process.

Comment: This is a good thing given I already have a model corresponding to a json file. But I do not have a model.